# How to create database structure like google calendar

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-structures, database-schema

I have a project where users have personal calendar. In Calendar user can create chats, write notes, save files and etc. It's somethig like google calendar. So we have two tables Users and Calendar( it's tables of dates and link table for another entity (notes, files and etc) ). 
DB structures looks like [image: db strucutres]

But here we have some problem. For one user we generate 365 rows in calendar(or 366 in leap year) so if we have 100 users we have to generate 36500 rows per one year.. i think its not a good way. Can u recommend me good way to solve that problem?

Comment: In one table, store a date and and an activity. Separately, store a user associated with that date-activity. If you like, you can also have a calendar table with all practical dates, but there's not need for this, as it can be managed just as easily at the application level.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer @Strawberry . But i don't understand u clear. Do u mean that  i need a table where i saved information of date, activity type and activity id ? So that table have reference to user  and reference to many other table(entities). Tables have columns(id user_id entity_type entity_id) where entity_type -  where we have to get information(notes, files and etc) entity_id - id in that table

Comment: Typically, you might have a table of events (what's happening when) and a table of attendance (who's participating in that): `events(event_id*,event_title,event_datetime)`,`attendance(event_id*,user_id*)` - \* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @Strawberry okey, let's imagine 1000 users create 3 entity on one date. For example they created 2 notes and add 1 files. So on events table we have 3000 on one event_datetime . Is it okey ? Or if u can - draw structures please , maybe i dont understand what do u mean.

Comment: Yes, that seems fine. 3000 different event_ids, all with the same datetime

Comment: I would expect many more than 365 rows for each user every year. I would expect there to be one record for each user event. So if a user wrote 4 notes, had 3 appointments, and stored 1 file all in a single day, there would be 8 records for that user for that day. If your users actually use the system, I would expect well over 100,000 records for those 100 users in a single year. *And that's okay.* 100K records is trivial for a database to store and query.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to store a row for every day of the year. That's redundant if a user doesn't have an event that day, and doesn't work if they have more than one event that day.

A user hasMany (or one) calendars

A calendar hasMany events

An event starts at a datetime and ends at a datetime

(or starts at a date and ends at a date and is an allDay event)

You'll probably find that you need recurring events at some point, in which case things get complicated quickly. For this, use RFC 5545 RRules and ExRules and create "virtual" events using a materialized view.